# How is MySQL's AUTO_INCREMENT column reset

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Few question about resetting MySQL's AUTO_INCREMENT column.

First without deleting/creating a table, or deleting rows via TRUNCATE TABLE (see footer for that code) -- is this the correct way to do it?

```
ALTER TABLE [insert_TABLE_name] AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Next, is value set to `0` or `1` -- and why?

Bonus, any extra advice.

Comment: It's set to whatever you use in the alter table query, which is `1` in your case. However, since you're not deleting rows, you've now probably set yourself up for a primary key violation, since your next inserted row will try to use that `1` and conflict with a previously created row with the same key.

Comment: @Marc B: +1 If "TRUNCATE TABLE [insert_TABLE_name];" is the way, post that as the answer, with info on why "ALTER TABLE [insert_TABLE_name] AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;" will work work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's set to whatever you use in the alter table query, which is `1` in your case. However, since you're not deleting rows, you've now probably set yourself up for a primary key violation, since your next inserted row will try to use that `1` and conflict with a previously created row with the same key.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to any that have already been used.

you are trying to put the auto_increment counter back to 1, but it's already higher than that value, and as you cannot reset it to a value that's less than any value that's already been used, it doesn't work.